# Configure email alert for any job/workflow failures in Hue/Oozie?

Tags: email, notifications, oozie, hue, oozie-workflow

I would like to get email notifications if any job/workflow failed in Oozie. I am using Hue to monitor the workflows.

I don't want to add email action in each and every workflow because I have around 60 workflows already running.

I am also aware of the approach of sub-workflow, even with this approach I have to edit all my 60 workflows and restart co-coordinator to reflect the change.

Is it possible in Oozie or Hue to get notification for any job failures without modifying the workflow? Can we configure something at Oozie/Hue level to get email notifications?

Comment: You can develop a script to periodically query the Oozie server for recent _FAILED_ or _KILLED_ (or _SUSPENDED_) workflows / coordinators and send mail alerts. Would that be simpler than rebuilding all workflows in a clean way? No.

Comment: Note that Hue has a clunky interface with Oozie server API and a clunky workflow editor. Nothing else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no option out of the box, [Oozie SLA](https://oozie.apache.org/docs/4.1.0/DG_SLAMonitoring.html) connecting to your monitoring is often used for that. But this would require an update of the workflows.

In the future, an option could also be added to Hue to automatically add the email action on failure to any workflow, but this would need to be [developed](https://docs.gethue.com/developer/).

Without touching your workflows you would need to scrape the Oozie jobs API, but this is also kind of rebuilding the wheel.